# c++ if my program runs on eclipse will it run on linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I have a working program on eclipse but my professor plans on running it through linux. Does that mean i have to do all the argc argv stuff? If so, Im ok with that. But if it can run on linux without doing so thats even better because the argc argv stuff is kinda confusing at times.

Anyone know if my program will run?

these are my header files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
```

Comment: It would be much easier to tell if your program is going to run or not if you posted your code here, or perhaps just listed the header files that you included.

Comment: Have you been programming on a Windows machine? if so, have you been using any of the Windows APIs? or types or anything else?

Comment: Best to check it, I used to ssh to the uni computers and make sure my programs would run on the environment it would be tested on. Better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: What? "I have a working program on eclipse but my professor plans on running it through linux" <- do you think Eclipse is an OS? "i have to do all the argc argv stuff?" <- You don't have to include argc and argv if you don't want to. "the argc argv stuff is kinda confusing" <- Then learn C properly. A function with arguments should not be confusing at all...

Comment: It's more dependent on what operating system you're running Eclipse on than that you're using Eclipse, so you need to give us that info.

Comment: im on windows. these are my header files #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no guarantee that it will run. If you are not doing anything esoteric it should be fine. Depends on the complexity of the program as well as what compiler on linux is being used as well as what APIs are being used (for e.g. if you are using WINSOCK APIs they won't be available on Linux).

The best way is to try to run it on Linux.

Also, do you know what the "argc/argv stuff" is? Omitting those in the main() method usually should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should compile your code on the same platform that it will be run on.  You should also fully test the program on that platform you plan to run on.  If you don't have a unix environment you should go get one or install one on a virtual machine.